# Is there any publicly available/self-hosted OPRF service/implementation?

Tags: oprf

I've recently implemented & hosted an Oblivious Pseudo-Random Function (OPRF) based on [multiparty/oprf](https://github.com/multiparty/oprf) i.e. [Burns et. al. EC-OPRF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/111) as an AWS Lambda function / API, that can be recurrently used providing an ID (or getting a random one assigned). Also did some web searches prior and after, but haven't ran across anything similar, yet. So, does anybody of you know any publicly available OPRFs or projects/repos that allow their easy deployment/self-hosting?
If not, I'm going to publish my Lambda implementation (only if there isn't anything comparable and more mature / better supported, yet).